# Vertx Service Discovery alternatives

Tags: vert.x

Can I do Vertx Service Discovery without Hazelcast or are there alternative cluster managers, i.e., in my local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Other Vert.x installations I have seen use Zookeeper for discovery. Hazelcast has a Zookeeper discovery SPI if that's the route you want to take.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I have used kubernetes native discovery mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Vertx supports a number of discovery services. These include:

1. Hazelcast - default discovery service
2. Consul bridge
3. Zookeeper discovery
4. Kubernetes bridge
5. Docker link bridge .etc.

The choice of discovery mechanism is left to the developer. Check on vertx official documentation for more information [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-discovery/java/).